# IE does not wrap RTL paragraph around floated element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a floated element like `img` or `div` followed by a `p`.

```
<div style="float:left;">float.</div>
<p style="direction:rtl;">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</p>
```

It works as expected in other browsers, but IE fits the paragraph text to a narrow column.

http://jsfiddle.net/kYDgL/723/

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ScottS. I wanted to know if there is any way I can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the css to

```
#container{
    width: 400px;
    background: yellow;
}
p {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: right;
}
#floated{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}
```

here is the fiddle hope this works for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/kYDgL/724/

Comment: Thanks, but I want the text direction to be right-to-left.